# Why is this data not being displayed in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I am retrieving data from an Access database using `CoolStorage`, and can successfully populate a Team `DataGridView` by setting its DataSource as `Team.List()`.

However, I want to use a LINQ query on the result set to return the number of users for each team. As this screenshot shows the result is being returned fine, however the `DataGridView` displays no data. If I switch the `DataSource` to be `Team.List()` it displays the teams without any problems (though obviously not the number of users).

Is there something I need to do in order to use the LINQ result as a DataSource? I can get round this by adding a property to my Team class, however I don't understand why I can't use the LINQ result.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you saying that the grid displays no records at all? Or that it's not properly displaying the count?

Comment: Your snapshot shows the entities hydrated just because you expanded the Results View. It actually says so right next to it.

Comment: It displays no records at all, but displays the teams fine if I add this.dgvTeams.DataSource = Team.List() immediately after the last line

Comment: have you tried changing `this.dgvTeams.DataSource = d;` to `this.dgvTeams.DataSource = d.ToList();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to materialize your datasource before it can be used.

Try changing

```
this.dgvTeams.DataSource = d;
```

to

```
this.dgvTeams.DataSource = d.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ uses deferred execution. That is, you have built your LINQ query but it will not actually be evaluated to produce results unless you add a method or aggregate on the end of the query to force immediate evaulation, or you can enumerate the result.

Try using...

```
this.dgvTeams.DataSource = d.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but what has confused me is that when using LINQ-to-SQL (as opposed to querying a CoolStorage result with LINQ, as here) just setting the query result as the DataSource is enough for the data to be displayed